# HTML files not loading in another html file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to load HTML inside HTML Tabs, I've three tab **Report 1, Report 2 and Report 3** Based on each tab selection I would like to show the different html reports but HTML file is not getting loaded when I select the tabs - please find my code below. Am I missing anywhere here and please find my reports file here - https://github.com/mikemarsh27/jest-poc/tree/main/html-report

It would be really appreciated if someone can help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

**reportMain.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<body>

    <div class="w3-container">
        <h2>Reports</h2>

        <div class="w3-row">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openReport(event, 'Report1');">
                <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">Report 1</div>
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openReport(event, 'Report2');">
                <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">Report 2</div>
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openReport(event, 'Report3');">
                <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">Report 3</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div id="Report1" class="w3-container report" style="display:none">
            <h2>Report 1</h2>
            <p>First Report</p>
            <div w3-include-HTML="report1.html"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="Report2" class="w3-container report" style="display:none">
            <h2>Report 2</h2>
            <p>Second Report</p>
            <div w3-include-HTML="report2.html"></div>

        </div>

        <div id="Report3" class="w3-container report" style="display:none">
            <h2>Report 3</h2>
            <p>Third Report</p>
            <div w3-include-HTML="report3.html"></div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function openReport(evt, reportName) {

            getHtml(reportName);
            var i, x, tablinks;
            x = document.getElementsByClassName("report");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-border-red", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(reportName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.firstElementChild.className += " w3-border-red";
        }

        function getHtml(id) {
            alert(id)
            //Get the <div> element
            let element = document.querySelector("#" + id)
                .querySelector("div");

            //Check if it's empty; we don't want to reload twice
            if (element.innerHTML.trim() !== "") {
                return;
            }

            //Get the HTML filename from the <div>
            let htmlFile = element.getAttribute("w3-include-HTML");
            alert(htmlFile)

            //Load the HTML file into the page
            element.innerHTML =
                `<object type="text/html" data="${htmlFile}" ></object>`;
        }


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are showing and hiding the `<div>`s here, but nowhere in this file are you actually fetching the external HTML.  That isn't done automatically.  You have to make an AJAX request to fetch the file and place the contents into the `<div>`.

Comment: ah..ok. Sorry I'm not  a front-end guy...that's why i was not able to relate the Ajax issue.. could you please help me with one example. I'll do the same for rest of them. Appreciated!

Comment: You copied this from an example, right?  The example shows how to do this.  This example fetches all of the nested HTML at the start.  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided appears to be from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp). They provide additional steps that will probably make your code somewhat functional. I say somewhat because the report files you're looking to load in contain more than just HTML. Therefore, their examples may not ultimately work for you.

Here is a rough, but working solution:

### Step 1: Add this function to your code

```
function getHtml(id){
     //Get the <div> element
     let element = document.querySelector("#" + id)
     .querySelector("div");

     //Check if it's empty; we don't want to reload twice
     if (element.innerHTML.trim() !== "") {
          return;
     }

     //Get the HTML filename from the <div>
     let htmlFile = element.getAttribute("w3-include-HTML");

     //Load the HTML file into the page
     element.innerHTML=
     `<object type="text/html" data="${htmlFile}" ></object>`;
 }
```

### Step 2: Call getHtml(...) in openReport(...)

```
function openReport(evt, reportName) {
     getHtml(reportName);

     ...
}
```

A modified approach is provided below. In your specific circumstances it may not work, so I would stick with the first one. But for others in a similar situation, it may be more reasonable.

```
function getHtml(id) {
     //Get the <div> element
     let element = document.querySelector("#" + id)
     .querySelector("div");

     //Check if it's empty; we don't want to reload twice
     if (element.innerHTML.trim() !== "") {
          return;
     }

     //Get the HTML filename from the <div>
     let htmlFile = element.getAttribute("w3-include-HTML");

     //Get the HTML file contents
     fetch(htmlFile).then(function(data) {
         return data.text();
     }).then(function(data) {
        //Got the HTML file contents; print it to the page
        element.innerHTML = data;
     }).catch(function(err) {
         // Report error here (e.g., console.warn(...))
     });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Siege. I updated the code with your changes but for some reason html page is not getting loaded inside the tabs - am I missing anything here? I've updated the original post with your code for reference.

Comment: 1. Can try Ctrl+Shift+i & check for any errors under the "Console" tab. 2. And try switching out the <object> for an <iframe>, and see if that leads to anything informative (e.g., element.innerHTML= `<iframe src=${htmlFile} width=...>`). 3. I'd ensure the HTML report files and the HTML tabs file are all in the same directory on your server/computer. The code loads from a relative path, as I'm sure you know. 4. But if you modified the code to load the report files from GitHub or the such for testing, then that most likely won't work because of X-Frames-Options or Content-Security-Policy.